# Load data Height and width fit to screen in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am trying to load a video in webview. It works fine.

However my video is being loaded in small size.

My code is below:

```
webView.loadData("<html><body> <script type='text/javascript'>ch='" + ChId + "'; ch_width=1080; ch_height=720;</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://m.s247.tv/live.js'></script> </body></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

I want the video to fit the screen.

Comment: @Maharith Aditya Not Working

Comment: @Maharith Aditya Please give Example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the display width and height.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Then in the web view, set the width and height:

```
webView.loadData("<html><body> <script type='text/javascript'>ch='" + ChId + "'; ch_width="+ width +"; ch_height=" + height" +";</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://m.s247.tv/live.js'></script> </body></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

You can calculate aspect ratio too and set the height as aspect ratio.